# Backchecking on python regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression match

I'd like to match c99 in files, so long as its not part of a hexadecimal color code for example

- Do NOT match on  `#000c99`
- DO match on `/mysite.com/c99.php`
- DO match on `%20c99.php`
- DO match on `c99?hi=moo`

Is this even possible with regex?

Comment: yes. use a negative look behind assertion

Comment: @Joel Cornett - I believe they work for fixed width only do they not

Comment: The [regex module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) contains a new regular expression implementation which allows variable-length lookbehind.

Comment: What if the code is part of a URL fragment? /mysite.com/index.php#c99

Comment: Also, something about parsing HTML using regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [the regex module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/):

```
>>> rx = regex.compile(r"(?<!#\d{0,3})c99")
>>> rx.findall("#000c99")
[]
>>> rx.findall("/mysite.com/c99.php")
[u'c99']
>>> rx.findall("%20c99.php")
[u'c99']
>>> rx.findall("c99?hi=moo")
[u'c99']
```

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward way would be to match lines with "c99" in them then discard any where the c99 is in a color code:

```
line = fileHandle.readline()
while (line) :
     if (re.search("c99", line)) :
          if (re.search("#.?.?.?c99", line)) :
               pass
          else :
               # line contains c99 not in a color code
     line = fileHandle.readline()
```

There's probably a way to do it within a single regex, but this was just the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to do it regex only so that I can avoid writing a macro language system, it won't be the only pattern its used for but in the same circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `(^([^#].*?)?c99.*?$)`

Comment: This will fail to match cases where c99 occurs on a line with a hex color code before it (e.g., it will not match `"#000FFF followed by c99"`).  Also it matches the entire line, not the c99 itself.

Comment: i expect that all text would be splitted into words, or regex would be hard and long

Comment: That's a rather big assumption.  Anyway, the regex needn't be too huge even if you want to find c99 in arbitrary text.